# Why do I hear a flushing sound from the bathtub when the toilet is flushed?

Tags: plumbing

When I flush the toilet, I can hear the toilet flushing sound from my bathtub. What causes that and what can I do about it?

Comment: If you pour a pint of water into the tub, does the sound stop, or start somewhat later in the flush?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer. Please revise to tell us more about your home: age, plumbing type, any layout information you have, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they share the same vent.  At some point all your drains need to breathe, so there is a pipe that lets air into the system.  Think about a large bottle of water turned upside down when open.  If there is no vent, it glugs.  If there is a vent, it flows out smooth.  So when they share the same vent you hear the other events trough the other pipes.

Comment: If there's water in the trap you should not hear much of anything....

Comment: So what's the solution? This is vague speculation without a fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by inadequate venting. The vent pipe is either clogged or too small.

It is sucking the water out of the p-trap and that is why you hear it.

Installing an AAV after the p-trap under the sink should solve that problem.

Comment: That's a bold suggestion with such meager knowledge of the plumbing situation. We just discovered that the roofers who redid my parents' home recently left tape covering both plumbing vent terminations. There are many possible causes and just as many potential solutions. A little humility may be in order.